# How to relate tables when one table is a count of products

Tags: sql, join, database-design, architecture

I have one table with products (ID, name) and another with clients (ID, name, phone number).
Also I know the number of each product that each client buys,

i.e. Client 1 buys 30a, 20b, 100c, and 0d

Client 2 buys 10a, 10b, 10c, and 10d

etc

I know how to make the table of products and the table of clients, but how do I relate both tables? For instance, if I want to show the name of the products that Client 1 buys, how can I do it?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a 'relation' table that link clients and products.

I suppose the buying information are in a separate table (ClientProductRelation) with columns:
- ClientID
- ProductID
- Quantity (needed only if you want to know how much products a client buy)

Then, using the JOIN statement, you can obtain full information:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cl.Name, pr.Description
FROM ClientProductRelation AS cpr 
JOIN Clients AS cl ON cpr.ClientID = cl.ID 
JOIN Products AS pr ON cpr.ProductID = pr.ID
```

(I know TOP 1 is not the best choise, but it is the fastest one)

Hope this help!

Comment: The problem is that I have 6 products but 500 clients.
I'm sure there must be an alternative way rather than 3000 entries of the Client_ID-Product_ID-Quantity table

Answer (score 0):

Make a table of transactions/orders (id, Custid, Prodid, quantity, datetime).
That way you can do things like:

```
SELECT 
    c.name, 
    p.name,
    o.quantity, 
    o.id,
    o.datetime

FROM 
    orders o 
JOIN 
    customers c 
ON o.custid = c.id
JOIN products p
ON o.prodid = p.id

WHERE c.id = 1
```

Comment: Cheers but what I want to avoid (if possible) is to create a table with customer_id and product_id. 500 costumers and 6 products is a lot...

The exercise present the table as I said, I think the trick is there...but in any case I can think of, there are both ID in the table...

Comment: you could make a 4th table that is composed simply of an id, customer id, and product id, and then put the relation id in a table with the quantity and time of purchase, but that is just extraneous work and I don't know why you would want it.(possibly for an index based on customers purchasing products?)

Comment: keep in mind that the table I suggested would have an entry per customer per order of product, a lot more than 500*6 rows, but the table would still be tiny as far as data tables go.